# Why does Ruby throw an error for alternate hash syntax?

Tags: ruby

I am coming from a Perl background and learning Ruby. I am bit confused about Ruby's hash syntax.

I am referring to the example given on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html

My Ruby throws a syntax error for the alternate syntax which is mentioned in the above link.

This code works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
options = { :font_size => 10, :font_family => "Arial" }
puts options[:font_size]
```

Whereas, this code throws a syntax error:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
puts options[:font_size]
```

The error is:

```
/home/workspace/ruby/so.rb:3: odd number list for Hash
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
```

However, the link pasted above says that it should work.

Could you guide me what I am missing here? Or did I overlook something obvious?

BTW, here is the Ruby version that I am using:

```
# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
```

Comment: That syntax only works in Ruby 1.9+. You're using 1.8.

Comment: @Blender, I kind of guessed that, but don't have 1.9 handy to confirm. Thanks, I will update my ruby to 1.9. Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to upgrade to 1.9. 2.0 is reverse compatible with 1.9. If you are upgradng, do it to 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9. You are using a version earlier than that. You should not be using Ruby 1.8 any more. Look at this page: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ruby that came default on my ubuntu 10.04. I will update it right away.

Comment: Your Ubuntu is also old. You should upgrade that first.

Comment: True. I know, but I will stick to 10.04 as I don't like all later versions of ubuntu due to GUI changes.

Comment: I agree that the default GUI on the latest Ubuntu sucks. So do many people. You can use classic GUI with the latest Ubuntu. It does not come as default, but with a few settings, you can.

Answer (score 4):

That syntax only works in Ruby 1.9 or later.

Note that the page you reference says "Ruby 2.0" in the title.

Comment: Good catch. I did not notice that. I searched for ruby doc and started referring it. thanks.